# How to print an escape character in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, escaping, ascii

I have a string containing an escape character:

```
word = "x\nz"
```

and I would like to print it as `x\nz`.

However, `puts word` gives me:

```
x
z
```

How do I get `puts word` to output `x\nz` instead of creating a new line?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [String#inspect](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/String.html#method-i-inspect)

```
puts word.inspect #=> "x\nz"
```

Or just `p`

```
p word #=> "x\nz"
```

Answer (score 1):

> I have a string containing an escape character:

No, you don't. You have a string containing a newline.

> How do I get `puts word` to output `x\nz` instead of creating a new line?

The easiest way would be to just create the string in the format you want in the first place:

```
word = 'x\nz'
# or 
word = "x\\nz"
```

If that isn't possible, you can translate the string the way you want:

```
word = word.gsub("\n", '\n')
# or
word.gsub!("\n", '\n')
```

You may be tempted to do something like

```
puts word.inspect
# or
p word
```

Don't do that! `#inspect` is not guaranteed to have any particular format. The only requirement it has, is that it should return a human-readable string representation that is suitable for debugging. You should never rely on the content of `#inspect`, the only thing you should rely on, is that it is human readable.

Comment: What exactly is wrong with using `#inspect`? The docs say "Returns a printable version of str, surrounded by quote marks, with special characters escaped.". This sounds like exactly what the OP wants, and sounds like a perfectly reasonable definition of a 'format'. Can you clarify your objection?